# How to git ignore the 'target' and it's 'site' directories and particularly entire 'site' content

Tags: git, serenity-bdd

[image]

In my Serenity Java testing project, after the tests have been run, the target and it's sub directory 'site' will be filled with tens of files and directories to display reports and screenshots.
Of course, I don't want to commit all those files in to git repository, and even don't want to  see them being tracked.
I did  do this in my .ignore file which is at the top level of the project along with pom.xml as shown.

```
## Any un needed file any where in the project file structure.

*.class

*.tmp

*.jar

*.html

*.png

*.json

*.csv

*.DS_Store



# any eclipse project file.

.eclipse

.classpath



## All the folders underneath site folder

**/site

site/

site/*



## target folder at the top level of the project structue and paths and contents underneath it

target/

target/*



## target folder at any level of the project structue

**/target

/target
```

[image]

I am still having the files come up as being tracked...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+forget+tracked+files

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following logic:

```
!target/
target/site/*
```

This should spare the `target/` folder while including `target/site` and all its subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

Those files have accidently tracked before, but `.gitignore` just works for the files that are not tracked. So adding a `.gitignore` "too late" results in "not works".

> I don't want to commit all those files in to git repository, and even don't want to see them being tracked.

You can use `git filter-branch` to [delete those files from the local history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#_removing_file_every_commit).

Comment: I don't need to delete the files from the local history, because, I never committed them at all, not even once. All I want to do is not see them in my git status. I want my 'git status' to be precise and up to the needed point.

Comment: @PraNuta You have accidently committed them before you added .gitignore, otherwise you won't see them "modified" "deleted" (those mean they are tracked).

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue. From the page at [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

First:

git rm -r --cached . 
git add .
Then:

git commit -am "Remove ignored files"